# iBooks series metadata

Tags: itunes, macos, books, metadata

In iBooks on 10.10, books can have series metadata as shown in the image.

What metadata do I need to add to an external epub (i.e. not from ibook store) so that it can be displayed as a series?

[image: series metadata]

Comment: You used to be able to edit lots of this information when books were part of iTunes. The Series title was an editable field that was put in to support TV shows. You can still see it when editing TV show metadata in iTunes under the Video tab (the field names were different for books).  Right now with the limited capabilities of iBooks (particularly the lack of metadata editing), it appears this info is tied to metadata from the iBooks storefront.  It's probably still in the iBooks SQLite DB though, so if someone knows how to poke around there I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I made it, but it's quite a bit tricky.

**Summary:**

You have to change the *Books.plist* file in *~/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks/Books* for the books you want to have in a series, and also you have to add rows in the *BKSeries-*.sqlite*  database on *~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iBooksX/Data/Documents/BKSeriesDatabase* for them and the series.

**Here's how I did it:**

The database has 4 tables: *ZBKSERIESCHECK*, *ZBKSERIESITEM*, *Z_PRIMARYKEY* and *Z_METADATA*. I only changed the first three tables. The "series" is treated just like a book in these tables.

1. Add the books and the series in table *ZBKSERIESCHECK*. The table has 5 columns.

   [image: The table has 5 columns]

   - *Z_PK* is the primary key. It has to be a sequential number.
   - *Z_ENT* and *Z_OPT* I just completed with a "1".
   - *ZDATECHECKED* is just the date the row is created. In my case it was auto-assigned.
   - *ZADAMID* is a unique code for the book or series.

   This is the table with the data I added.

   [image: ID of the books and series]

   The zAdamId I used are from Calibre, so I asume that you can use any number. Keep in mind that those numbers have to be different from the series/books you purchased.

   The row with the zAdamId "1" is my series, the others are the books.
2. Add the relationships within books and series in the table *ZBKSERIESITEM*. This table has 16 columns.

   [image: Table ZBKSERIESITEM]

   - *Z_PK*, *Z_ENT* and *Z_OPT* are not the same ones defined in the previous table. *Z_PK* has to be sequential and, *Z_ENT* and *Z_OPT* I just completed with "2" and "1" respectively.
   - *ZISCONTAINER* defines if a zAdamId is a series or not. "1" is true, "0" is false.
   - *ZPOSITION* defines the number of a book in a series, starting with "0" for the first book.
   - *ZADAMID* is the same defined in the previous table for the same item.
   - *ZAUTHOR* is the author of the series/books.
   - *ZGENRE* is the genre of the series/books.
   - *ZSEQUENCEDISPLAYNAME* defines how a book is displayed as a member of a series. For example, for the first book, you can define "Book 1" or "Volume 1" or "Vol.1". This string is going to be prepended to the name of the book. This column has to be empty for the series.
   - *ZSERIESADAMID* is the series zAdamId of the book. For the series, this is the same as *ZADAMID*.
   - *ZSERIESTITLE* is the name of the series.
   - *ZSORTTITLE* and *ZTITLE* is the name of the book or series.

   [image: Table ZBKSERIESITEM contents]
3. Adjust table *Z_PRIMARYKEY*.

   I found that this table has only two rows. One for each of the previous tables.

   [image: Table Z_PRIMARYKEY]

   Here you have to change the *Z_MAX* column to the MAX(*) value of the *Z_PK* in each of the previous tables. For instance, in my DB, for the table *ZBKSERIESCHECK* (*BKSeriesCheck*) the MAX(*) of the column *Z_PK* is "22".
4. Save the changes.
5. Open the *Books.plist* file. Look for each of the books of the series and add these keys:

   - *seriesAdamId* as *Number* with the value of *ZBKSERIESITEM~ZSERIESADAMID*.
   - *itemId* as *Number* with the value of *ZBKSERIESITEM~ZADAMID*.
   - *seriesSequenceNumber* as *String* with the value of *ZBKSERIESITEM~ZPOSITION + 1*. (Remember that in the table it starts with "0".)
   - *seriesTitle* as String with the value of *ZBKSERIESITEM~ZTITLE*.

   [image: Books.plist file]
6. Save the file. Close iBooks (if you didn't close it from the beginning). Kill the *com.apple.BKAgentService* process. Start iBooks. You should be able to see your series.

   [image: Results]

**Notes**

Those columns I didn't name, I just left them empty and it didn't affect the end result.

I think it's waaay to difficult to put all your books and series properly when you have a lot of them. Hope to see someday something that do all this auto-magically.

This is my first post. I hope everybody finds it useful.

Comment: Can anyone confirm if this still works? I'm having trouble with it.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution:

1. Go to the iBooks store and download the samples for the books you are trying to work with.
2. Change the extension from .epub to .zip.
3. Extract the zip and delete the folder named "OPS" (OEBPS for comics).
4. Locate the eBook you have and change from .epub to .zip.
5. Extract it and locate OPS.
6. Move OPS to the sample ebook folder.
7. Select all files in the sample, and create a .zip.
8. Change the extension to epub.
9. Do the same for each book in the series.
10. Drag-and-drop into itunes.
11. Synchronize and there you go!

Be carefull while going into the iBook store though, if you see the ebook you edited, it will have a button saying "update." DO NOT click update, or you will have to do it over again.

A whole lot easier than having to edit sqlite, and it works on both Mac and Windows.

Comment: Will this work for SRMed ebooks?

Comment: If it's in the iBooks store as a sample then yes.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that, in iBooks, I have a book (*Inheritance*) which iBooks highlights as a member of a series (in my case called 'Eragon' instead of 'The Farseer Trilogy'). In order to investigate this, I downloaded *Inheritance* and stripped the DRM using Requiem (on an old virtual machine) so I could poke about in the source code of the book.

Unfortunately, I have bad news. I used Sigil to search for the word 'Eragon'. The word 'Eragon' appears nowhere in the metadata within the epub, indicating that this is not possible; iBook evidently maintains series information separate to the actual epub files.

Comment: That interesting, note that I still think it stored locally somewhere maybe in ibooks sqlite database, since when I added 2 books in another series, they were grouped together when not connected to the internet

Comment: You mean you added two books from an external source, or you bought two books through iBooks?

Comment: I brought them on a different computer then transfer them to a computer with ibooks but no internet.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it myself, and found out, that the playlist in same folder that stores the epubs has informations about the book series. There are the metadata seriesTitle and
seriesSequenceNumber set. But unfortunately changing it there does´t make Ibooks to list books as series.
Also setting Metadata in the e-book itself saying series Title and seriesSequenceNumber is not working. 
Then I found a folder in usr. Library containers com.apple.IBooksX Data Documents BKSeriesDatabase, but it contains a SQL Database. Maybe the information is stored there.