# How do I create a 'series' of iBooks not originally purchased as a series from the iBooks Store?

Tags: iphone, itunes, books, epub

Is it possible to create a series of iBooks from epubs not donwloaded from the iBooks store?

For example, I have all the series of "Game of Thrones" in epub format (not purchased from the iBooks Store), but when I synchronise these books in iTunes to my iPhone or iPad, they appear in a different order and do not appear as a series (e.g. Book 1, Book 2, Book 3 etc).

Is there any way to make these books appear in a series as per the image below? **Note:** I did check this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151741/ibooks-series-metadata), but it didn't work for me.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at Calibre? It’s a free ebooks editor and it will allow you to change the metadata of the Ebooks to sort them how you want.

Comment: Yes, I tried with calibre but  even when you change the series in the metadata, and you syncronize in the iphone still appearing separate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iBooks series metadata](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151741/ibooks-series-metadata)